# Disable zoom/pinch zoom in Firefox on Mac

Tags: macos, firefox, zoom, gestures

Is it possible to disable zoom in Firefox altogether?

I work as a web developer and sometimes those odd off pixels is caused by the page being unintentionally zoomed in Firefox.

I do most of my work on a MacBook Unibody, where it's quite easy to activate pinch zoom unintentionally. Just being able to disable pinch zoom (in Firefox only) would be a great help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FireFox you can go to the " about:config " page to change the way the browser handels gestures including pinch for zoom.  Just filter for gesture and change the behavior there:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Setting browser.gesture.pinch.in / browser.gesture.pinch.out to null seems to have disabled pinch zoom. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the program 'Multiclutch' will do this for you. I have had no personal experience with it though so have a bit of a read first :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://cubeyellow.blogspot.com/2009/01/mac-book-pro-trackpad-zooming-and.html) disables touch gestures in Safari, Firefox and Mail.app